# React form validation with Yup and Formik for nested object is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have a form with nested object something like this,

```js
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  // ...
  isMultiDestination: Yup.boolean(),
  dropOffDestination1: Yup.object().shape({
    place_id: Yup.string().when("isMultiDestination", {
      is: true,
      then: Yup.string().required("Please enter destinaton 1")
    })
  }),
  dropOffDestination2: Yup.object().shape({
    place_id: Yup.string().when("isMultiDestination", {
      is: true,
      then: Yup.string().required("Please enter destinaton 2")
    })
  })
  // ...
});

const detailsForm = useFormik({
  validateOnBlur: true,
  validateOnChange: true,

  initialValues: {
    // ...
    isMultiDestination: false,
    dropOffDestination1: initPlaceObject,
    dropOffDestination2: initPlaceObject
    // ...
  },
  validationSchema: schema
});
```

After toggling the value of `isMultiDestination` and validating the form, the errors are not updated.

Validation is failing.

Comment: Are you sure that `isMultiDestination` is becoming `true` to trigger the validation?

Comment: Yes, the value of `isMultiDestination` is getting updated.

Comment: Updating like this `detailsForm.setFieldValue('isMultiDestination', newValue);`

Comment: Sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-form-validation-gs7qum

Answer (score 0):

try to set  validationSchema like this:

```
validationSchema: yup.object().shape({ yourValidationSchema }),
```